# Firebox Edge 11 and SBS 2008 VPN produces error 721

Tags: vpn, windows-sbs-2008, firebox

My VPN has stopped working.

I have sbs 2008 and have run the VPN wizard. I have opened the port 1723 on my firebox edge as it instructed me to do. It was working but I think that an upgrade of the firebox software to version 11 has affected it. The port is still open.

When connecting I get to verifying username and password then I get Error 721.

Not sure whats wrong here. can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that everything with the server and firebox was fine. in fact it was the router in the location I was trying it from. DOH!